# How to show $|e^{it}-\sum_{k=0}^{k=n}\frac{(it)^k}{k!}|\leq \frac{|t|^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, approximation

$$\left|e^{it}-\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{(it)^k}{k!}\right|=\left|\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}\frac{(it)^k}{k!}\right|=\frac{|t|^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}\left|\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(it)^k}{(n+2)\cdots(n+1+k)}\right|$$

Is the term inside the modulus somehow less or equal to $1$?

Comment: @CalumGilhooley That´s right!

Comment: @Doug It´s a pity the other answer has been deleted though, it could have been repaired easily

Comment: @Calum I'm starting with $k=0$ here. There's a $1$ to begin with.

Comment: What you have left in the sum is  $\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}\frac{(it)^{k-(n+1)}}{(n+2)..k}$ where for $k=n+1$ the demoninator is just the empty product i.e. 1, then you change the summation index $j=k-(n+1)$ to get $\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\frac{(it)^j}{(n+2)...(j+n+1)}$

Comment: I've corrected it. Thanks

Comment: You´re welcome! Now @Doug´s idea works with the argument $k!<(n+2)...(n+k+1)$ and what follows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use
$$
\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}t}  - \sum\limits_{k = 0}^n {\frac{{(\mathrm{i}t)^k }}{{k!}}}  = \frac{{(\mathrm{i}t)^{n + 1} }}{{n!}}\int_0^1 {\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}tx} (1 - x)^n \mathrm{d}x} 
$$
for any real $t$. Then
\begin{align*}
\left| {{\rm e}^{{\rm i}t}  - \sum\limits_{k = 0}^n {\frac{{({\rm i}t)^k }}{{k!}}} } \right| &= \frac{{\left| t \right|^{n + 1} }}{{n!}}\left| {\int_0^1 {{\rm e}^{{\rm i}tx} (1 - x)^n {\rm d}x} } \right| \\ & \le \frac{{\left| t \right|^{n + 1} }}{{n!}}\int_0^1 {\left| {{\rm e}^{{\rm i}tx} } \right|(1 - x)^n {\rm d}x} \\ & = \frac{{\left| t \right|^{n + 1} }}{{n!}}\int_0^1 {(1 - x)^n {\rm d}x}  = \frac{{\left| t \right|^{n + 1} }}{{(n + 1)!}}.
\end{align*}

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with the integral form of the remainder of a Taylor series of a complex-valued function of a real variable, but am I at least right in thinking that that is the source of the first displayed equation?

Comment: Great answer. Thanks.

Comment: @CalumGilhooley Assume that $z>0$. With the change of variables $s=zx$, the original integral remainder for $\mathrm{e}^z$ becomes $$
\frac{1}{{n!}}\int_0^z {{\rm e}^s (z - s)^n {\rm d}s}  = \frac{{z^{n + 1} }}{{n!}}\int_0^1 {{\rm e}^{zx} (1 - x)^n {\rm d}x} .
$$ Now by analytic continuation, this is valid for all complex $z$, in particular for $z=\mathrm{i}t$.